# Java updated to Java 8 but not able to locate folder in /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines folder on mac and not able to update java in android

Tags: java, android

I recently updated from Java 6 to Java 8 and it was successful.
I checked using this command:-
java -version

which is returning me:-

java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)

This command is also saying that Java 8 is installed and the path is what I have asked in the question:-
/usr/libexec/java_home
returning:-
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home

I also updated JAVA_HOME variable and getting $JAVA_HOME as:-
-bash: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_141.jdk/Contents/Home: is a directory

But I am not able to locate "jdk1.8.0_141.jdk" folder in "JavaVirtualMachines".

Please help me. I am building an android app which needs Java 8 and my android studio is not able to take Java 8 because I am not able to locate folder "jdk1.8.0_141.jdk"

Note : I have downloaded java 8 jdk from oracle.

Please find attached screenshots for more clarifications
[image: System Preferences showing that Java is updated to Java 8]

[image: Terminal Screenshot showing that there is no folder for jdk for Java 8]

I need to use Java 8 in one of my android app. Although I updated to Java 8 successfully(Please see screenshot) in android studio. But still I am getting the error that 
"Error:Gradle 3.3 requires Java 7 or later to run. You are currently using Java 6."
And
"NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1"

And the contents of my app level gradle file are:-

NumberFormatException: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1: Invalid revision: 24.0.0-alpha1

Answer (score 0):

The `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` folder is only used for the old Apple Java 1.6

The Oracle Java 8 installs in the `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines` folder. You must specify this location to anything that wants to know where Java is located.

Comment: Thanks a lot @greg-449 I found it.

Comment: Can you please help me in my updated question as well?

Comment: Sorry but I don't use Gradle or Android Studio